# Load page, save cookies and load another page with cookies

Tags: http, cookies, emacs, elisp, emacs23

How I can load page with POST parameters, save response cookies, save cookies, and load another page with saved cookies in emacs lisp?

In other words, I need analog to this bash code:

```
#!/bin/sh

LOGIN=SOMELOGIN
PASSWORD=SOMEPASSWORD

# Save cookie
curl -d "login=$LOGIN&password=$PASSWORD" -c /tmp/some.cookie http://stat.somesite.ru/

# Load page
curl -s -b /tmp/some.cookie http://stat.somesite.ru/ > /tmp/some.page

# Manipulations with saved page....
```

If any manuals, code sources, etc exists -- let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to execute those commands with the `shell-command` function and/or its derivatives (q.v., [Running Shell Commands from Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell.html)).

Comment: Yes, I know, but I want clean elisp solution.

Comment: In that case, you could look into using `w3m` or the `URL` packages, the latter of which I believe is now part of the standard distribution. Unfortunately, I don't have much experience using either, but I suspect that availing yourself of the relevant pages on the [Emacs Wiki](http://emacswiki.org/) would be useful.

Comment: Yep, I'm tryed use url.el, but it almost hasn't any documentation ( only http://emacswiki.org/emacs/UrlPackage ) about work with cookies.